# Resetting Virtual Instrument volume in Musink composer

Tags: audio, midi, notation

I am using the [free notation software Musink](http://musink.net) to compose music. My music plays back through a virtual MIDI cable that is connected to a group of virtual instruments, as described in [Musink's Help](http://wiki.musink.net/doku.php/midi;playback) Wiki. I have set each stave's volume in my Virtual Instruments, but every time Musink starts playback, the volume of my virtual instruments resets. This changes how my composed score sounds.

Is this caused by Musink, or by Windows? Can I snoop on the MIDI data somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is a setting in Musink. The notation editor does this on purpose so stuff doesn't stay muted if muted by another composing program. Browse to:

Tools -> Options -> Playback and MIDI

Uncheck "Send channel volume messages".